# "TypeError: need a summation variable" and variable scope in Sage program

Tags: function, scope, sage

I tried to make a summation list in Sage. The commands were:

```
sage: var('n')
sage: var('x')
sage: f = (2/n)*(sin(n*x)*(-1)^(n+1)) 
sage: funclist = [sum(f,n,1,20) for n in range(1,3)]
```

but it was error:

```
TypeError: need a summation variable
```

but when i tried some similar things on python shell. There was no any problem.

```
>>> x=1
>>> [pow(x,2) for x in range(1,9)]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64]
```

and return to Sage, there was no problem if i run program on Sage like this:

```
sage: var('n')
sage: var('x')
sage: sum(f,n,1,20)
-1/2*sin(4*x) + 2/3*sin(3*x) - sin(2*x) + 2*sin(x)
```

I don't know how Sage combine a 'sum' function into its program. And don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sage shell is different from the Pytyhon shell, and the function `sum` is different too. In Sage, it tries to find a *symbolic* sum, that's why the second argument needs to be a *variable*. In your first code block, you are essentially trying to evaluate

```
[sum(f, 1, 1, 20), sum(f, 2, 1, 20)]
```

From the mathematical point of view, how do you sum over `1`? That's why Sage gives you an error. Notice that in the last code block, when you use the variable `n`, Sage is able to calculate the sum.

Comment: For cross-reference, a very similar answer was accepted at http://ask.sagemath.org/question/3149/sage-showed-typeerror-need-a-summation-variable